# Can't access $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] when using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm calling a php script as follows:

```
$data="param1=P1";
$data.= "param2=P2&"; 
$data.= "param3=P3";  

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL," http://www.example.com/readcurl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Now in the receiving script (readcurl.php) I can read the params through:

```
$par1= $_REQUEST['param1'];
$par2= $_REQUEST['param2'];
$par3= $_REQUEST['param3'];
```

I want to check if all the parameter have been supplied. But when I do

```
count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
```

this gives "1" as the count.
When supplying the parameters from within a browser:

```
http://www.example.com/readcurl?param1=P1&param2=P2&param3=P3

count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
```

gives '3'

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: There is no [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) portion in the URL supplied to cURL. You would have the same problem if trying to use `$_GET['param1']`, for the same reason. Reading the documentation for `$_REQUEST` should explain why it still works in this case.. even *without* a query string.

Comment: Thanks, so argc would be possible?

Comment: 'argc' is irrelevant. It would be possible to access the query string *if and only if* such was supplied. As previously stated, it is not supplied. The link in the first comment should explain what the query string is, and it should be clear why such a query string is *not present* in the URL used. (The cURL code and the URL accessed from the browser are different.) You should also take this time to read about the CURLOPT_POST/POSTFIELDS options to be clear about what they actually do.

Comment: Ok, having read the links (and hopefuly understanding most of it) $_REQUESTis not the correct way to get the params, what is?

Comment: $_REQEST will read from POST-data *and* the Query String, *should* such be present. In the code / requested URL **there is no query string**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very long answer above/below.

Here is the TL;DR and best practice way which urlencodes the data properly:

```
$dataArray = array(
    'param1' => 'data1',
    'param2' => 'data2',
);

$postData = http_build_query($dataArray, '', '&');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

In the receiving script, you check

```
$_POST['param1']
```

because POST data does not get appended to the QUERY_STRING

Answer (score 3):

You are setting `POST` parameters:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL," http://www.example.com/readcurl.php");
//This line is not needed, and in fact it should produce a warning
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
```

...but are attempting to read `GET` parameters (which would be in the URL, ie. the `QUERY_STRING`):

```
count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
```

You *could* simply count the `$_REQUEST` array instead:

```
count($_REQUEST);
```

...but since this can very easily break I would recommend strongly against it unless you have absolute control of the entire application, don't expect any users other than yourself, and never expect to add another parameter.

I would recommend explicitly checking each parameter instead:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['param1']) && isset($_REQUEST['param2']) && isset($_REQUEST['param3'])) {
    //All parameters are here, get them
    $param1 = $_REQUEST['param1'];
    $param2 = $_REQUEST['param2'];
    $param3 = $_REQUEST['param3'];
}
```

Further I would recommend against using the `$_REQUEST` superglobal in general - it contains all `POST` parameters, all `GET` parameters and all `COOKIE` parameters. This means that you are giving up some amount of control, and thereby (in the worst case) opening up you application to unnecessary security vulnerabilities - or in the best case increasing the complexity of future debugging.

Instead you should access the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) directly - I would recommend going with `$_POST` whenever you can:

```
if (isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2']) && isset($_POST['param3'])) {
    //All parameters are here
    $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
    $param2 = $_POST['param2'];
    $param3 = $_POST['param3'];
}
```

...oh - and you have a typo here:

```
$data="param1=P1";
$data.= "param2=P2&"; 
$data.= "param3=P3";
```

(ampersand missing between param1 and param2)

To avoid having to manually construct a valid querystring you should be able to simply pass an array to curl like this:

```
$data = array(
    'param1' => 'P1',
    'param2' => 'P2',
    'param3' => 'P3'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL," http://www.example.com/readcurl.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

All of the curl options are quite well-documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)